# Profiling a .net library

Tags: c#, .net, vb6

I'm referencing a class in a .net library in VB6 and need to profile it.  Is there a profiler that can be pointed at a .net library dll?

The memory issues I wish to profile only happens when used in the VB6 application.  The pure .net test application for the library does not have memory issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your VB6 application inside a profiler like [JetBrains DotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html) or [ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm). Although the application is VB6, at least DotTrace should be able to see the managed .NET library calls.

Comment: Thanks, DotTrace gave me everything i needed.